# Is it possible that google direction api takes in consiration my own polylines for precise results? => Android

Tags: android, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I'm a beginner in the development for android, and I'm working on a small application integrating the Api `google map` and `direction`.
My app is based on an area in which google map did not consider all the routes, so I had to create my own polyline, and I would like them to be taken into account in the itinerary calculation of the direction api. I did some research but without any expected result.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I am sincerely sorry for this delay in my reaction.
in my code I used the retrofit library for tracing routes, and what I would really like to know is how to make sure that google direction api also takes into consideration my polyline for more accurate results. Thank you for the time you give my preocupation.
below the main file code "Mainfragment.java"